# Display an image, some text trimmed with ellipsis, and then an icon

Tags: html, css

I want to have all of these on the same line, not multiple lines. However, when I try to do this, I end up with multiple lines. You can check out my [fiddle here](https://jsfiddle.net/r7d0ss6c/)

I tried this for my css:

```css
.left-img {
  height: 34px;
  width: 34px;
  margin-right: 12px;
  vertical-align: middle;
}
.right-img {
  height: 34px;
  width: 34px;
  margin-right: 12px;
  vertical-align: middle;
}
.container {
  max-width: 300px;
}
.text {
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
  font-size: 18px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <img src="https://c1.staticflickr.com/7/6217/6357645479_b6d8c2d367_z.jpg" class="left-img" />
  <span class="text">my Text that should wrap in elipses before the icon right?</span>
  <img src="http://rlv.zcache.co.nz/zoom_up_of_cat_face_large_square_tile-r9ff2bcd4ac1d49e9b01fc97b9d0993c6_agtbm_8byvr_50.jpg" class="right-img">
  </i>
</div>
```

but its not working.

I want to have the container at a fixed width. How can I accomplish all of this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using flexbox is great for this (produces better result than @dippas's answer):

#### [Demo page](https://jsfiddle.net/r7d0ss6c/1/)

```css
.left-img {
  height: 34px;
  width: 34px;
}

.right-img {
  height: 34px;
  width: 34px;
}

.container {
  max-width: 300px;
  display:flex; /*  <--- add this  */
  align-items: center;
  outline:1px dashed #CCC; /* can delete this */
}
 
.text {
  font-size: 18px; 
  padding: 0 12px;
   /* <--- add this  */
  text-overflow: ellipsis; /*  <--- add this  */
  white-space: nowrap; /*  <--- add this  */
  overflow: hidden; /*  <--- add this  */
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <img src="https://c1.staticflickr.com/7/6217/6357645479_b6d8c2d367_z.jpg" class="left-img" />
  <span class="text">my Text that should wrap in elipses before the icon right?</span>
  <img src="http://rlv.zcache.co.nz/zoom_up_of_cat_face_large_square_tile-r9ff2bcd4ac1d49e9b01fc97b9d0993c6_agtbm_8byvr_50.jpg" class="right-img" />
</div>
```

By the way, you could also give the clipped text element a `title` with the same text, when the mouse hovers it, the user could read the whole text.

Comment: what do you mean? you can clearly see it works. it should be flexbox so the text would take all the possible width, unlike your solution..

Comment: @dippas - maybe on your browser, which is probably Chrome, which I never use.

Comment: @dippas - the output of your code seems different on my machine then... it is cut: `my Text th...`

Comment: @dippas - It doesn't even makes sense for your solution to work, because nothing tells the `span` to stretch as much as possible...it wouldn't know to do that without being a flex-item... agreed?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/116718/discussion-between-vsync-and-dippas).

Answer (score 2):

you are missing a few properties to make `ellipsis` work, you need to add to `.text`:

- `white-space: nowrap`
- `width: (some value)`
- `display: (inline-)block` , because this is `span`(inline element)
- `overflow: hidden`

remove duplicated classes with same properties, merging them.

```css
img {
  height: 34px;
  width: 34px;
  margin-right: 12px;
  vertical-align: middle;
}
.container {
  max-width: 300px;
}
.text {
  white-space: nowrap;
  width: 100px;
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: middle;
  overflow: hidden;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
  font-size: 18px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <img src="https://c1.staticflickr.com/7/6217/6357645479_b6d8c2d367_z.jpg" class="left-img" />
  <span class="text">my Text that should wrap in elipses before the icon right?</span>
  <img src="http://rlv.zcache.co.nz/zoom_up_of_cat_face_large_square_tile-r9ff2bcd4ac1d49e9b01fc97b9d0993c6_agtbm_8byvr_50.jpg" class="right-img" />
</div>
```

If you don't want a fixed `width` in your span `.text` then you can use flexbox (as @vsync already answered)

```css
img {
  height: 34px;
  width: 34px;
  vertical-align: middle;
}
.container {
  max-width: 300px;
  display: flex;
  border: red dotted
}
.text {
  white-space: nowrap;
  overflow: hidden;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
  margin: 0 12px;
  font-size: 18px;
  align-self: center
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <img src="https://c1.staticflickr.com/7/6217/6357645479_b6d8c2d367_z.jpg" class="left-img" />
  <span class="text">my Text that should wrap in elipses before the icon right?</span>
  <img src="http://rlv.zcache.co.nz/zoom_up_of_cat_face_large_square_tile-r9ff2bcd4ac1d49e9b01fc97b9d0993c6_agtbm_8byvr_50.jpg" class="right-img" />
</div>
```